# MediaElement.js knowing when player goes fullscreen

Tags: mediaelement.js

i need check every time player goes fullscreen (or goes out from fullscreen), in other words, i need to listen to a custom event when the fullscreen method is triggered so i can do other things below.

Comment: I'd also like to know the answer to this.  When mediaelement goes into flash fullscreen it screws up the controls.  I'd like to try and fix them.

Answer (score 6):

You'll need to add this bit of code before initializing MediaElement:

```
MediaElementPlayer.prototype.enterFullScreen_org = MediaElementPlayer.prototype.enterFullScreen;
MediaElementPlayer.prototype.enterFullScreen = function() {
    // Your code here
    this.enterFullScreen_org();
}
MediaElementPlayer.prototype.exitFullScreen_org = MediaElementPlayer.prototype.exitFullScreen;
MediaElementPlayer.prototype.exitFullScreen = function() {
    // Your code here
    this.exitFullScreen_org();
}
```

Comment: I would lay this script as an add-on to the original script by adding something like "this.dispatchEvent('enterfullscreen');" instead of the plain code. This way it could be handled as any other event without getting your code dirty. Of course the best course of action is to fork from the repo and make the actual implementation!!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, there is an `"enteredfullscreen"`event being dispatched when opening the fullscreen mode. However, this event is not being dispatched on the `mediaElement`, but on the `player`.

You can either attach the event listener after initiating the player:

```
var myPlayer = new MediaElementPlayer("#video", options);

myPlayer.container.addEventListener(
    "enteredfullscreen",
    // your callback function goes here
    false
);
```

or use the `success` callback function (just add the `player` as the third argument):

```
var myPlayer = new MediaElementPlayer("#video", {
    // your options
    success: function(mediaElement, domObject, player) {
        player.container.addEventListener("enteredfullscreen", yourCallbackFunction)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find a solution to this problem as well. My solution is to watch the `isFullScreen` property of the Mediaelement player object for changes.

Sample code:

```
...
var mejsFullScreen;
new MediaElementPlayer('#video', {
    pluginPath: 'lib/mediaelement/',
    flashName: 'flashmediaelement.swf',
    success: function(mediaElement, DOMElement, player) {
        mejsFullScreen= mediaElement.isFullScreen;
        setInterval(function() {
            if (mediaElement.isFullScreen != mejsFullScreen) {
                if (mediaElement.isFullScreen) {
                    // do something on enter fullScreen
                    mejsFullScreen = mediaElement.isFullScreen;
                } else {
                    // do something on leave fullScreen
                    mejsFullScreen = mediaElement.isFullScreen;
                }
             }
         }, 500);
    }
});
```